# Google Drive Api v3 Create Shared File

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using Node.js google-api client for creating file in google drive normally when i create file everything work fine , here is an example :

```
drive.files.create({
      resource: {
        name: 'Another File 5',
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
      },
      media: {
        mimeType: 'text/plain',
        body: 'It\'s Another Fucking File',
      }

    }, function(err,result){
        if(err) console.log(err) 
        else console.log(result)
    });
```

Now i want create a shared  `"shared": true` its give me this error :

```
drive.files.create({
  resource: {
    name: 'Another File 5',
    mimeType: 'text/plain',
    "shared": true
  },
  media: {
    mimeType: 'text/plain',
    body: 'It\'s Another Fucking File',
  }

}, function(err,result){
    if(err) console.log(err) 
    else console.log(result)
});
```

Error :

```
{ [Error: The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.]
  code: 403,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'fieldNotWritable',
       message: 'The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.' } ] }
```

I tried this in Google APIs Explorer and gave same error.

I am new to google Api and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `shared` attribute on the request body of `create`. This has been discussed

Its discussed int he [Share Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing) section of the Drive API documentation, you'll need to call [`drive.permissions.create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) and set the appropriate permission of the account you'll share with.

I tested this on the API Explorer as well, and it works.

```
var fileId = '1sTWaJ_j7PkjzaBWtNc3IzovK5hQf21FbOw9yLeeLPNQ';
drive.permissions.create({
    resource: {
        'type': 'user',
        'role': 'writer',
        'emailAddress': 'example@appsrocks.com'
    }, 
        fileId: fileId,
        fields: 'id',
    }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Permission ID: ', res.id)
        drive.permissions.create({
            resource: {
                'type': 'domain',
                'role': 'reader',
                'domain': 'appsrocks.com'
            },
            fileId: fileId,
            fields: 'id',
            }, function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                // Handle error
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Permission ID: ', res.id)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i knew about `drive.permissions.create` and already using this , i just want know this is possible and apparently it's not.