# Trying to add properties to files in TeamDrive using Drive API v3 for Java and a service account

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm trying to add properties to files that have already been uploaded to a TeamDrive using the Drive API and a service account. I can access the files, but when I try to add a properties map to a file object and update() I get a 403 error.

```
...

Drive.Files.List request = service.files()
    .list()
    .setIncludeTeamDriveItems(true)
    .setCorpora("teamDrive")
    .setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
    .setTeamDriveId("MAZEPX3fk38ieDu9PVL")
    .setQ("name contains 'aad081cc-0929-42bf-88f9-cb43c5ed0742'");

FileList files = request.execute();
File f = files.getFiles().get(0);
Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("fancyTag", "this_is_my_tag_value");
f.setProperties(props);
service.files().update(f.getId(),f).execute();

...
```

and it blows up with a com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException:

```
{
    "code" : 403,
    "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.",
        "reason" : "fieldNotWritable"
    } ],
    "message" : "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
}
```

The service account has edit access to the TeamDrive in question. In the v3 docs, it says explicitly that properties are writable. So I'm wondering what have I not set, or what conditions have I inadvertently created to disallow setting properties on drive files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931936/how-to-use-appproperties-in-google-drive-api-v3) related to your problem.

From there, you will be re-directed to the notes that was written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration).

If you will read it, there is this part in the answer:

> **Trash / Update**
>
> I wasted some time with this one . Used to be a simple
>   `service.files().trash(fileId).execute()`. Docs say
>
> ```
> files.trash -> files.update with {'trashed':true}
> ```
>
> The [example code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) for `update` on v2 makes a `get` on the file,
>   sets new values and then calls `update`.
>
> On v3, using `update` like that throws this exception:
>
> ```
> {
>   "code" : 403,
>   "errors" : [ {
>     "domain" : "global",
>     "message" : "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.",
>     "reason" : "fieldNotWritable"
>   } ],
>   "message" : "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
> }
> ```
>
> The solution is to create an empty `File` setting only the new values:
>
> ```
> File newContent = new File();
> newContent.setTrashed(true);
> service.files().update(fileId, newContent).execute();
> ```
>
> Note: `File` refers to `com.google.api.services.drive.model.File` (it
>   is not `java.io.File`).

For further reading, here are some related post

- [SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212019/unable-to-update-google-drive-files-using-drive-api-v3-the-resource-body-incl)
- [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775338/google-drive-api-v3-create-shared-file)

Comment: You are my hero. Spot on.